# I need help identifying this resistor

Tags: resistors

[image]
I read it as 1 ohm 5% tolerance 250 ppm/k but I can’t seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: If you can read the color code, what more do you want? One 1Ω±5%, 250ppm/K resistor is the same as any other 1Ω±5%, 250ppm/K resistor.

Comment: I can’t find it to purchase it.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/resistors/through-hole-resistors/53?keywords=&sort=&pv2085=u1+Ohms&pv3=2

Comment: Any 1Ω resistor will do, pretty much.

Comment: @Felthry. Not if it has to be flame proof.

Comment: This should work: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-bc-components/NFR25H0001008JR500/PPC1-0BTR-ND/614121

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it is a 1 ohm 5% 250 ppm resistor. Looks to be *metal film and flame proof*. Looking at the circuit it looks like a reactive power supply, becoming more common these days for LED night-lights, etc.

The AC line goes through the resistor which limits in-rush a bit and can be a fuse if it has to be. The capacitor is next and is likely 470 nF to 680 nF to allow a few tens of milliamps to feed the bridge rectifier made of SMD diodes which feed a 9V to 12V zener and bypass cap, which feed a IR motion detector or sound detection IC to activate an LED.

Notice the small MOV on the AC hot and neutral inputs (maybe after the resistor). They could have saved a few pennies, but why risk it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I’ve looked at several sites and still am having a problem finding this combination. It is from an led light. Is there any more common resistors that could be substituted? I

Comment: It is NOT a common resistor. Because it taps current off the AC line it must be flame proof metal film, which can act like a fuse. Try Digikey/Mouser/Allied Electronics. They all have parametric search engines to pin down what you need. Avoid Ebay like the plague.